# Map information - Providing info about a local business on a webpage (NPE) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, mobile, npe, us20120284613a1

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON Showing information about local businesses on a map on a webpage** - This application from Abra Inc. seeks to patent the idea of...Showing website visitors a map containing information about local businesses! This application is now owned by a presumed patent troll known as "FAN CHIANG HOLDINGS"

10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 11/18/1999** that discusses:

> - Showing a web page with a map based on user selected geographical information.  In reponse to user request, showing a second web page with more information about a local business on the map.  (Note **1999 priority date** of application.)

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - User selected information is a **zip code** or location of local businesses are shown with **markers** on the map

**TITLE: Providing local business information on a website**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Send user a first customized web page which includes **a map** localized to any geographical area specified by user.  Sending a second web page with more information pertaining to businesses on the map (in response to user request).

- **Publication Number**: [US 20120284613 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120284613)
- **Application Number**: US 13/551,267
- **Assignee**: FAN CHIANG HOLDINGS (presumably an NPE/patent troll)
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 11/18/1999
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 5/7/2013
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20120284613#c=0&d1&d2=11%2F18%2F1999)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1. Sending, by a first computing device to a second computing device, a first web page customized based on user selected information and including map information localized to a user selected geographic area; and
> 2. Responsive to a request for information pertaining to a business indicated on the first web page, sending, by the first computing device to the second computing device, the requested information in the form of a second web page customized based on the business and including information pertaining to the business.

In English this means:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1. Sending a web page customized in any way based on **user selected information** which includes a **map** localized to some geographical area selected by the user; and
> 2. In reponse to the user requesting more information about a business on the web page, Sending a second web page customed with more information pertaining to the business.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 11/18/1999

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming User-entered zip codes and local businesses indicated with map markers

---

**"Method of providing sequence data to the cloud computing environment" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: This patent appears to cover display of local business information based on provided criteria, including zip code. http://www.google.com/patents/WO2000025190A2 It does not explicitly cover returning results on a map from what I am able to determine.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but I think this could be answered by a system, run by a single large business, which provided the location of their nearest branch based on a customer's zip or postal code.  I think it should be relatively easy to find examples of this in the early-to-mid dot-com era.

Answer (score 1):

In 1999 I did some brief consulting work for the company where2getit.com.  Their product was(is) a web application that allows people to locate stores close to their location.  Users can search by address and it would display stores on a map close to their location.

The company and product were created around 1997!

http://www.where2getit.com/about/

http://www.where2getit.com/solutions/business-locator/

Unfortunately the way back machine does not have any captures of their site prior to '99